# Count all rows in all tables in all databases

Tags: python, mysql

The script below works but does not give the row count.

I did try to find the answer here and try to change it but for some reason, most of the examples/ answers are using some specific table/ database.

And as mentioned in the question, I would like to do it on all databases/tables.

```
import MySQLdb
import json
import os,sys


serv = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="host")
result = {}
c = serv.cursor()
c.execute("SHOW DATABASES")
l = c.fetchall()
col_names = []
for db_name in l:
    name = db_name[0]
    c.execute("USE %s;" % name)
    c.execute("SHOW TABLE STATUS;")
    for desc in c.description:
        result.setdefault(desc[0], None)
        col_names.append(desc[0])
print(result)
```

Comment: The inner `for` loop has not been indented properly, fix that and post the edit. Also, please specify what exactly you want to do "on all databases" .

Comment: I mean it does run and show me the results.
{'Engine': None, 'Row_format': None, 'Update_time': None, 'Rows': None, 'Checksum': None, 'Name': None, 'Check_time': None, 'Index_length': None, 'Auto_increment': None, 'Data_length': None, 'Create_options': None, 'Avg_row_length': None, 'Data_free': None, 'Version': None, 'Create_time': None, 'Collation': None, 'Comment': None, 'Max_data_length': None}

 I want to count rows in tables in all databases.

Comment: Okay, so you want number of rows in all tables in all databases? Tell what you want to do on the database and it'll become easier to write that code in python.

Comment: Yes the main thing that I want is to add a query to existing script or create a completely new script that will count all rows in all tables in all databases. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` meta-database to get the row count for all tables in all databases.

```
import MySQLdb

serv = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="host", db="INFORMATION_SCHEMA")
c = serv.cursor()
c.execute("select table_schema, table_name, table_rows from tables")
l = c.fetchall()
print(l)
```

outputs (truncated and reformatted)

```
...
('mysql', 'slow_log', 2), 
('mysql', 'columns_priv', 0), 
('mysql', 'time_zone_transition_type', 0), 
('mysql', 'tables_priv', 0), 
('mysql', 'column_stats', 0), 
('mysql', 'func', 0), 
('mysql', 'innodb_index_stats', 2395), 
('mysql', 'innodb_table_stats', 423), 
('mysql', 'gtid_slave_pos', 0), 
('mysql', 'proc', 2), 
('mysql', 'time_zone_leap_second', 0), 
('mysql', 'db', 3), 
('mysql', 'help_topic', 508), 
...
```

Comment: I done it , and I got 3k characters in return , can not post all of then here in comment.
(('information_schema', 'CHARACTER_SETS', None), ('information_schema', 'COLLATIONS', None), ('information_schema', 'COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY', None), ('information_schema', 
etc
https://imgur.com/a/wqllCtC link of screen shot

Comment: If you only get `information_schema` output in there, your user might not have access to any other database.

Comment: I did change the permissions and now I can see all tables, https://imgur.com/a/t5v7iWb